# Mathematical explanation of transformations of Marginal Revenue

Tags: microeconomics, elasticity, nonexpert, marginal

MR = d(Total revenue)/dQuantity = d (Price * Quantity)/dQuanitity

This is the same as this : MR = P(Q) + dP/dQ

I did it with an example and it amazed me how both are equal but I still dont get how. They seem to be different formulas, maybe somebody can get from one to other step by step and then I can connect it.

Also, the second formulas makes that : MR = P(Q) * (1+ 1/elasticity(Q)) And then it is converted to: MR = P(Q) * (1- absolute value of (1/elasticity(Q))

This last step of converting the parenthesis in negative I guess its because usually the demand function looks like this : Q = 100 - P; Therefore the inverse demand : P = 100 - Q

That is what I'm guessing but I would appreciate a deeper explanation.

Comment: This is typically covered in an intermediate micro course. The trick is to note that in an inverse demand curve, price is a function of quantity, i.e. $P(Q)$. Because of this, you'd have to apply product rule when differentiating total revenue, and the result is your second expression of MR (which you missed a $Q$ at the end).

Answer (score 4):

You have two questions. The first one is (I broke lines in the quotes where I tought this improved legibility):

> MR = d(Total revenue)/dQuantity = d (Price * Quantity)/dQuanitity 
> This is the same as this: 
> MR = P(Q) + dP/dQ

As [Herr K. points](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/50878/why-marginal-revenue-equals-this#comment82240_50878) out, an important thing to note is that $P$ and $Q$ are not independent of each other; in this context $P$ is a function of $Q$. After this observation, the answer is purely mathematical: the product rule. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule):

> In calculus, the product rule (or Leibniz rule[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) or Leibniz product rule) is a formula used to find the derivatives of products of two or more functions. For two functions, it may be stated in Lagrange's notation as
>
> $ (u\cdot v)' = u'\cdot v+u\cdot v'$

---

Your second question seems to be

> MR = P(Q) * (1+ 1/elasticity(Q)) 
> And then it is converted to: 
> MR = P(Q) * (1- absolute value of (1/elasticity(Q)) 
> [...] converting the parenthesis in negative I guess its because... 
> ...I would appreciate a deeper explanation...

It is assumed that $P(Q)$ is decreasing in $Q$, and that both $P$ and $Q$ are positive. The (point) elasticity formula is
$$
\epsilon_P(Q) = \frac{\text{d}P(Q)}{\text{d}Q} \frac{Q}{P}. 
$$
The first fraction is negative (because $P(Q)$ is decreasing in $Q$), and the second fraction is positive (both $P$ and $Q$ are positive). Thus the quantity elasticity of price is indeed negative, and hence
$$
\epsilon_P(Q) = - | \epsilon_P(Q) |.
$$

Comment: Thanks!!! Really helpful everybody